# Azure and Sendgrid connection issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, sendgrid

I finally was able to deploy an app to Azure after altering my identity and EF conn strings in Azure.

I setup Sendgrid first because my mvc app sends email confirmation for user registration.  It worked wonderfully locally and I was very pleased how seamless it was.  However, when trying to integrate with Azure it's not registering anything.

Locally I added my API key as an environment variable on my local machine and it worked.  This is the code:

```
 private async Task configSendGridasync(IdentityMessage message)
    {               
        //For Local
        string apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("my_sendgrid_key");

        dynamic sg = new SendGridAPIClient(apiKey);

        Email from = new Email("senders@email.com");
        string subject = message.Subject;
        Email to = new Email(message.Destination);
        Content content = new Content("text/plain", message.Body);
        Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);

        dynamic response = await sg.client.mail.send.post(requestBody: mail.Get());
    }
```

Following [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email) I added it as an app setting variable in Azure just as the app says.  Sendgrid gave me an api key that i kept, i just didn't include it in this screenshot:
[image]

It looks verbatim to the code and azure setup in the documentation link provided, what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure it's the key that's not reading? Are you able to make a test page which prints out the environment variable? Perhaps something else is broken.

Comment: I'm actually not sure thats it.  Ill try  to do a new prod build and show the api key.. because it absolutely works locally.

Comment: Ok, just confirmed it's not getting my key.  It shows in local on my page but in prod does not.

Comment: Actually, thats not true.  I queued a new build but the changes jsut aren't reflecting in the prod azure environment.....

Comment: Was able to finally test this and the key is being shown on the page in production.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that not the code issue. And we could remote debug the Azure website in the local  VS dev tools.
More info about how to remote debug WebApp, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#a-nameremotedebugaremote-debugging-web-apps). After that we may easily to find out the issue.

Base on my experience, if the sender email equals to the receiver email then there is no error and no email send out.

After add the AppSetting in the Azure portal, we also need to save the value manually. From your screenshot, it seems that the setting is not saved.

[image]

If  it is single instance WebApp, we also could check the environment variables info from the kudu tool. (https://yourwebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net)

[image]

Comment: Hi Tom thanks for the reply.  I just  did that exact thing and checked kudu and its showing my api key!  As far as putting the actual api key in as a value im doing that as well i just omitted it from my screenshot

Comment: I looked at the doc and i dont have Publish when i right click my solution.  Im using VS 2016 Developer edition

Comment: It is very odd that `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("my_sendgrid_key")` can not get the appsetting value. It works correctly for me. Please have a try another way to get the  `my_sendgrid_key` value, `apiKey  = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["my_sendgrid_key"]`;

Comment: Before i do this i have a question.  I am using continuous delivery.  When i push a build then a release, why aren't my new changes showing?  Is there something else i have to do

Comment: Nvm, had to release to get it to work.  Im gonna take a break its late and i have work then ill try this tomorrow.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: the appsetting didnt work because of this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/03/20/storing-your-secrets-in-azure-websites-app-settings/

Comment: I stayed up and fixed it.  In azure, i kept trying to do continuous development.  Well, i didnt do that and added my own (probably wrong, but working) build and release definitions.  Then i manually build and released my code to the web app. it finally sends a confirmation email consistently.